# php $_GET is it interpreted as single quoted or double quoted string?

Tags: php, directory-traversal

I'm making the assumption that $_GET variables are interpreted as single quoted strings (and not double quoted strings).

I believe this is true because of the following test (trying to directory traversal attack myself):

```php
$file = "../test.php";
/**
* same as file1 but using hexadecimal encoding, which is a feature
* only available to double quoted strings
* https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
*/
$file2 = "\x2e\x2e\x2ftest.php"; 

include $file1; // will succeed in my environment
include $file2; // will succeed in my environment
```

However, if I pass the hexadecimal notation via $_GET, it fails including
the file:

```php
$file3 = $_GET["path"]; // (string) \x2e\x2e\x2ftest.php
include $file3; // will fail in my environment
```

So my question is: is it really the case that $_GET variables are interpreted as single quoted strings?
(because if so then maybe a simple removing of two consecutive dots from the user input would prevent any directory traversal attack)

And if so, is it written anywhere in the php manual?

Comment: why would you include a file based on the value of $_GET variable?

Comment: They are not “interpreted” as strings in any way, they simply _are_ string values. You are confusing _data_ with _code_ here. Single vs double quotes is only relevant in the latter.

Comment: They are strings. Only PHP has the single quote / Double quote thing. As they are passed about the ether they are just byte buffers that equate to a string when they get to PHP

Comment: `$file3 = realpath($_GET["path"])` might do the trick

Comment: I guess the answer to your question is simply "no", because string values don't have "quotes" and are just data.  The quotes are used when defining string *literals* in your code.  If the value you receive in your GET is `\x2e\x2e\x2ftest.php` then that's the value you have.

Comment: `$_GET` variables are __just strings__, they are not interpreted in any way.

Comment: *"I'm making the assumption that `$_GET` variables are interpreted as single quoted strings"* -- you are making a confusion. Single quotes and double quotes are a way one can mark a fragment of a source code as raw text (i.e. data) and not code. `$_GET` is a variable that contain strings, i.e. raw text, that are extracted from the URL; there is no source code involved.

Comment: *"maybe a simple removing of two consecutive dots from the user input would prevent any directory traversal attack)"* -- that's a naive assumption. Never use user input as file paths. Ever. No matter how careful you are, a malicious user (in fact a script) will always find a way to trick your code into including a completely different file instead.

Comment: If values in `$_GET` variables were interpreted as strings then `\'` in the input would be interpreted as ``\``. It is not.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:
$_GET['path'] is a Variable. PHP will interpret escape sequences only if it found in double quotes, not in a variable. -> [Strings Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
$get = "\x2e";
var_dump($get);  
//string(1) "."

$get = "\\"."x2e";
var_dump($get);
//string(4) "\x2e"
```